# How to know if specific alert dialog is shown by webpage (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am making a Chrome extension that runs a code when a web page's specific alert dialog is shown to user.
(By alert dialog, I mean Javascript's 'window.alert()')
I want to detect the alert dialog's text, and run a code.
Is there any way for Chrome extension to detect alert dialog's text shown by the web page?
Or any other way to detect alert dialog?

For example, a foreign website alerts a user by `window.alert("Banana pie")`.
My extension will detect 'Banana' and run a code.

Comment: You can override window.alert in [page context](/a/9517879).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code but try to call a function instead of an alert. For example in part of code where you put `alert('something')` put a function that will make that alert and do whatever you want too.
And you can also make a function that takes alerts text:

```
 function getAlert() {

  // get all scripts
  var elem = document.scripts;

  // loop and check
  for (var i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {

    var txt = elem[i].textContent.match(/alert\(['"]([^'"]+)['"]\)/);
    if (txt) { return txt[1]; } // if matched, return the alert text and stop
  }
}
```

Took this from [How to get text from alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578897/how-to-get-text-from-alert-box)
Hope this helps

Comment: Ah I meant 'when' a website alerts a user, my code will run 'at that time'. Not just checking whether if the website has that alert.
Also, I am dealing with a website made by others(not me), so I can't just change that website to call my function.

Comment: Ooooh, well sorry, don't know then.